# Tabu command replacement

Tags: tables, tabu

I am currently setting up a fresh `LaTeX` environment and trying to incorporate all my old files. They use the `tabu` package a lot. Since it is very outdated, giving errors etc. I decided to replace it with a similar, but updated package.

Question 1: Is there a current package out there that provides the same features as `tabu`? I saw some latex-table-package-overviews, but most of them list `tabu` as "all-rounder" with the comment: don't use it, but without advice for a replacement.

Question 2: We have **a lot** of tabus, thousands of them. It would take weeks to go through all the documents and replace them all. Can you imagine a possibility to create a self-made tabu-environment based on a possible package (from Question 1). Ideally I will be able to define this globally and the files with tabus will still be working and the tables appear as close as possible to the old one.

**Edit:**

The features we use mostly are

- the "to"-specifier for a given width of the tabu
- the horizontal adjustment properties. Mentionable are the "standard" `X[1c]`, the semi-automatic `X[-1c]` and the math-mode-included versions as `X[-1c$]`; all also in combination with the syntax for a number n of those, like `n*{X[-1c$]}`
- `extrarowsep=..` as vertical alignment
- `\tabucline{-`} and `\tabucline{X-Y}`

I guess that would be our main uses of the tabu-features. There are also some longtabus in our works, but only just a few. I also have prepared an MWE (at least I tried as well as I can) for some of the mentioned features:

```
    \documentclass[a4paper]{article}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{tabu}

    \begin{document}
    \begin{center} 
    \begin{tabu}to 0.8\linewidth{|X[-1c]|X[-1c]|X[-1c]|} 
    \tabucline{-}
    Test & X & Y \\\tabucline{-}
    Test & Z & A \\\tabucline{-}
    \end{tabu}
    \end{center}

    \begin{center}
    {\extrarowsep=5pt
    \begin{tabu}to 0.7\linewidth{*4{|X[-1c$]}|}
    \alpha & \beta & \gamma & \delta \\\tabucline{2-3}
    \alpha & \beta & \gamma & \delta
    \end{tabu}}
    \end{center}
    \end{document}
```

**Edit 2:**

The fact that there is no solution conveys the impression that this (at least the general tabu features replacement) might be of some interest and something worth taking a deeper look. So for the first step I want to construct some tables with the same features and results but without using the tabu-package. As it might be the wrong place to expand this question any further, I started a new one here: [Tabularx with calculated column widths that use the whole table width](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/575637/tabularx-with-calculated-column-widths-that-use-the-whole-table-width)

Comment: Maybe you should clarify which features of `tabu` your files use. Then it may be easier to find a replacement. Maybe it is possible to define a pseudo-tabu packages based on another tabular package that provides just the required features

Comment: I'm not aware of a direct replacement.  If and how easily it is possible to define a self-made tabu depends a lot on which features you actually used.

Comment: you are right. I mentioned the main features and gave a MWE in my edit.

Answer (score 1):

The new LaTeX3 package [`tabularray`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray) is an alternative for the outdated `tabu` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\begin{document}
\begin{tblr}{width=0.8\linewidth,colspec={|*{3}{X[2,l]|X[-2,r]|}},rowsep=4pt}
\hline[1pt]
 1     & 2    & 3     & 4     & 5       & 6    \\
\cline{1-3}
 alpha & beta & gamma & delta & epsilon & zeta \\
\cline[dashed]{-}
 1     & 2    & 3     & 4     & 5       & 6    \\
\cline{1,3,5}
 alpha & beta & gamma & delta & epsilon & zeta \\
\hline[1pt]
\end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

[image]